# Python nested loops are transposing values after two loops, why are the x and y values are being transposed throughout this loop?

Tags: python

This is the python code, I am expecting numeric values for the x coordinate and x through z for the y coordinate.

```
 for x in range(0,6):
        for y in ["x","y","z"]:
            combo ={x,y}
            print(combo)
```

after several loops the values are transposed.

```
{0, 'x'}
{0, 'y'}
{0, 'z'}
{1, 'x'}
{1, 'y'}
{1, 'z'}
{'x', 2}
{2, 'y'}
{2, 'z'}
{'x', 3}
{3, 'y'}
{'z', 3}
{'x', 4}
{4, 'y'}
{'z', 4}
{'x', 5}
{'y', 5}
{'z', 5}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because sets aren't ordered, if you use a list, everything would be fine:

```
for x in range(0,6):
    for y in ["x","y","z"]:
        combo = [x, y]
        print(combo)
```

Output:

```
[0, 'x']
[0, 'y']
[0, 'z']
[1, 'x']
[1, 'y']
[1, 'z']
[2, 'x']
[2, 'y']
[2, 'z']
[3, 'x']
[3, 'y']
[3, 'z']
[4, 'x']
[4, 'y']
[4, 'z']
[5, 'x']
[5, 'y']
[5, 'z']
```

Comment: Thank you, up too late.  Was using sets instead of my desired tuples.